# How to find user entered string is base String literal or not in java?

Tags: java, string

Here I've base String called `String baseString = "nullpointer"`; if user entered some strings like `pointernull`, `llpointer`, `internullpo`  then it should print TRUE else FALSE. How to write the logic for this? please help me.

```
public class literalString {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String baseString = "nullpointer";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.next();
    //pointernull, llpointer, internullpo  then return TRUE.
    // pointerllnu, unpointerll  then return FALSE
    //what shoul be the logic here?
 }
}
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is logic behind this pointernull, llpointer, internullpo

Comment: `llpointer` --> is this right?. I am assuming you want to check for *circular equivalence*.

Comment: @Exbury,those are called string literals.Observer pointernull is in sequence i.e.,entire word pointer then null like circular order.The user entered string should check with base string.If its is in circular order then it should print true.

Comment: @TheLostMind,yes exactly but it should not end with llpointer.It should have like this llpointernull (completer whole word)

Comment: How can `llpointernull` be *correct* when your String is `nullpointer`?

Comment: @TheLostMind,sorry,It should be llpointernu.

Comment: So any "rotation" of the word is still correct? You could test the input string against all rotations or get more clever and figure out how the input string is a rotation of the target string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check `baseString.length==input.length`if it is fails then it is wrong
if it is true then check using `concat` and `contains`

**Simple example**

```
String baseString = "nullpointer";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.next();
    if(baseString.length()!=input.length()){
        System.out.println("false");
    }
    else{
        if(baseString.concat(baseString).contains(input)){
            System.out.println("true");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exbury,can you elaborate a little bit more please.

Comment: Exbury,It is not working for given input pointerllnu.Please check it once.

Comment: @khanam - again, `pointerllnu` is *invalid*, it's not *circular rotation*

Comment: TheLostMind, pointerllnu for this even false is also not printing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String[] valueList = {"pointernull", "llpointer", "internullpo"};

if(Arrays.asList(valueList).indexOf(input) != -1) {
    // User has typed "pointernull", "llpointer" or "internullpo"
}else{
    // User has typed something else
}
```

Comment: Michael Miriti,It is not fixed to 3,It should be more,then this logic fails

Comment: you can add or remove any amount of elements in `valueList` to keep the list of necessery values.

Comment: where does these "pointernull", "llpointer", "internullpo" comes from?

Comment: Michael Miriti,if valueList is 100 then?

Comment: It depends on where the data comes from. You can fill this array from file, database, network resource or simply hardcode it by hands.

Comment: Now I see that I didn't get your question in the first place :)

Comment: Michael Miriti,observe the answer of Exbury.Anyway thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
(base.concat(base)).contains(input);
```

So if your base is `nullpointer`, then `base.concat(base)` will yield `nullpointernullpointer`, and `contains` will return `true`on `nullp`, `pointernull`, `ointernu`, etc.